# HELP! Survey Modal TXT include not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css, colorbox

Working with this page here.
http://careersinmusic.com/index.aspx

The RED BAR, should open a modal window. And the survey SHOULD be inside. Coming up with an ERROR in my .TXT include.

```
<!--CSS-->
```

THERE IS MORE code. But the script tag wont let me show it.

Any help would be great.

This include has something wrong with it I think, not sure where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may there is a problem with comment tag spacing
write `<!-- CSS -->` instead of `<!--CSS-->` because some time these declarations also effect our layout.

for more check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_importance_of_correct_html_commenting